# Why React says "Logout is not a function ?"

Tags: reactjs

Please see below code that is throwing me "Logout is not a function" for some reason:

logout.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Logout extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.onLogoutUser();
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <p>You're now logged out. Click <Link to='/login'>here</Link> to log back in.</p>
    )
  }

};

export default Logout;
```

app.jsx (only relevant code shown):

```
import Logout from './components/Logout';

class App extends React.Component {

    logoutUser = () => {
      window.localStorage.clear();
      this.setState({is_authenticated: false});
    };

    
  render() {
 
    const { logoutUser } = this;

    return (
      <div>
      <Route exact path='/logout' render={() => (
                  <Logout
                    isAuthenticated={is_authenticated}
                    onLogoutUser={logoutUser}
                   />
                )} />
      </div>
  )
 }
};

export default App;
```

snippet of a traceback:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: this.props.onLogoutUser is not a function]
          at reportException (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
          at invokeEventListeners (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:209:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
          at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
          at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10021:16)
          at invokeGuardedCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10073:31)
          at commitRootImpl (/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13033:9)
          at unstable_runWithPriority (/usr/src/app/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12) TypeError: this.props.onLogoutUser is not a function
```

I'm really cornered as to why I'm getting error I shouldn't be getting. Any feedback
much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the error occurring? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: You forgot to `import` it.

Comment: @Quentin  My apologies. It's actually included I just forgot to include the import in the post.

Comment: @Dominic  I added snippet of the traceback to the question.

Comment: try in your app component `onLogoutUser={this.logoutUser}` instead of `onLogoutUser={logoutUser}`

Comment: @dikuw  Tried. No change. I'm glad it didn't work 'coz it would mean I have a bigger problem --> non-functional props destructuring.

Comment: Is the only place you are rendering the Logout component? You also don't need the arrow fn on componentDidMount. I don't think this will help but you should pass react-router props too - `render(props => <Logout {...props} isAuthenticated=... />`. Also it's unnecessary to add a constructor to your component unless you're using it for something (RE the current answer)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the props inside componentDidMount hook directly. However, you can access it on render hook. To use it on componentDidMount hook, you may use super with constructor:

```
class Logout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
```

Now, you can access the props in your componentDidMount hook as you did.

Also, you are using arrow method (public class method) to use componentDidMount hook, so you need to pass props param and use `props` instead of `this.props`. Or simply use:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // this.props
```